# Regex to match a number with decimals

Tags: c#, regex

I have the following regex:

```
var matches = Regex.Matches(s, @"ratingValue"" content=""(?<content>(?:(.|\n)(?!""></span>))+)");
```

However, it gives the output with "number.", anything after the `.` is not taken. For example, if the number is `4.0` it will output `4.` or if it's `3.5` it gives `3.`.

How can I get the decimals as well?

Example input:

```
<span itemprop="ratingValue" content="4.0"></span>
```

I need to output `4.0`.

Comment: um, i wouldn't use a regex to parse html.

Comment: If you want numbers, why not just use a `\d+`? Also, make the decimal part optional, with e.g. `\d+(?:\.\d+)*` It would also be helpfull if you gave us some example content and desired output.

Comment: You should totally drop that and try CSQuery. Or HtmlAgilityPack. Or AngleSharp.

Comment: @DanielA.White What would you use? Sorry if this is a noobish question.

Comment: @MaximilianGerhardt I've added an example in the post now. Sorry about that.

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski Thanks for the recommendations. My program is fairly simple and the HTML is static. I am definitely going to check these 3 for my bigger projects. Thanks again :)

Comment: In answer to the "What should I use?" - an HTML Parser. HtmlAgilityPAck was always a popular one

Answer (score 3):

You can use LINQ to XML:

```
string xml = @"<span itemprop=""ratingValue"" content=""4.0""></span>";

string content = XElement.Parse(xml).Attribute("content").Value;

decimal value = Convert.ToDecimal(content, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: I would use Linq To XML too. This might be shorter: decimal content = (decimal)XElement.Parse(xml).Attribute("content");

Comment: But how do I do this if my HTML is more than that? My example was just a small part of the whole HTML code.

Comment: @user5204184 - check this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387041.aspx

Comment: I'll check it out, but the HTML contains a lot of classes, so it might take a while to implement this (if I manage to do it).

Comment: Parsing HTML with XML parser is just a bit better than with RegEx... Because HTML is neither follow XML grammar nor regular expression grammar... (Suggesting to use HTML parser like HtmlAgilityPack would be an answer)

Comment: **HtmlAgilityPack** works like a XML parser; however, it is fault tolerant and will accept unclosed tags like `<br>` or `<p>`.

Answer (score 0):

I've changed your regex so it returns the decimal number as the match:

```
var matches = Regex.Matches(s, @"(?:ratingValue"" content="")(?<content>[\r\n\d\.]*)(?:""></span>)");
```

Is this what you were after? It returns 4.0 from the provided sample.